# How to keep JPanel in fixed size?

Tags: java, swing

Here's my JFrame before resizing:

[image]

And here's my JFrame after resizing:

[image]

I want only the JTextArea get bigger as a result of resizing and keep the upper part of the JFrame same size. Both the label("Threads program") and the button("Press to Start") are JPanels inside a JPanel.

Here's the constructor of this:

```
public ThreadsGUI()
{
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Threads program");
    cmdStart = new JButton("Press to Start");
    txtOutput = new JTextArea(15,0);
    lblTitle.setForeground(new Color(0,0,255));
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 24));
    txtOutput.setFont(new Font("Courier New", 0, 20));
    cmdStart.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,50));
    cmdStart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));

    JPanel label = new JPanel();
    label.add(lblTitle);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.add(cmdStart);

    add(label);
    add(buttons);
    add(txtOutput);
}
```

Comment: Do you know about [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) ?

Comment: @Abra Yes. How can I use it here to make it work?

Comment: Make the `JTextArea` the CENTER component and put the `JLabel` and the `JButton` in a `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` and make that `JPanel` the NORTH component.

Comment: @Abra Works perfect. The JLabel and the JButton are in the same line. How to put the JButton under the JLabel?

Comment: `GridBagConstraints`. For the `JLabel`, `gridx = 0` and `gridy = 0` and for the `JButton`, `gridx = 0` and `gridy = 1`.

Comment: @Abra Fantastic